# Query something and return the reason if nothing has been found

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

Assume I have a Query - as in [CQS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) that is supposed to return a single value.

Let's assume that the case that no value is found is not exceptional, so no exception will be thrown in this case. Instead, `null` is returned.

However, if no value has been found, I need to act according to the *reason* why no value has been found.

Assuming that the Query knows the reason, **how would I communicate it to the caller of the Query?**

A simple solution would be not return the value directly but a container object that contains the value and the reason:

```
public class QueryResult
{
    public TValue Value { get; private set; }
    public TReason ReasonForNoValue { get; private set; }
}
```

But that feels clumsy, because if a value is found, `ReasonForNoValue` makes no sense and if no value has been found, `Value` makes no sense.

What other options do I have to communicate the reason? What do you think of one event per reason?

For reference: This is going to be implemented in C#.

Comment: If your query result is `null`, what other reason besides 'not found' would you possibly expect?  Put another way, what are all the possible values for `ReasonForNoValue`?  If there's only one, then the presence of `null` would imply it.

Comment: @DanPichelman: My concrete context is a translation service and the query takes a key and a target language as input and returns the translation as a result. There are at least two reasons *why* a translation can't be found: (1) The key is unknown. (2) The key is generally known, but there exists no translation for the specified target language.

Comment: This is going to depend a lot on language I think, e.g. in ML family a sum type and pattern matching, but I suspect from your snippet that sum types aren't really doable for you

Comment: @jk.: I have never worked with ML. Could you explain shortly what that would do?

Comment: https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/pick-of-the-week/sum-types

Comment: something similar to [Discriminated union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminated_union). It can contain a value, or it can contain an error object (possibly an exception object with a message), but it cannot contain both. The recipient can choose to throw it, but the service can return the exception object without throwing.

Comment: Thanks to you both for the explanation. I think the simple case needed here could be simulated in C# with a marker interface `IQueryResult` without any members and multiple classes that implement it. However, because the concept of sum types and pattern matching is not widely known to C# programmers, that would be confusing.

Comment: This actually sounds like the right answer would be to throw an explanatory exception.

Comment: Exceptions should be thrown in *exceptional* cases. I consider a missing value not exceptional. It actually can be quite common in my use case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Many internet protocols are built around a response code that is always returned along with an associated message.  [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTP_transport_example) and [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Response_message) being two well known examples.

Thus, `public TReason ReasonForNoValue` becomes something more along the lines of `public TResponse ResponseCode`

The response could be an integer and follow the SMTP and HTTP style example, or it could be an enum for some type safety, or even a string (though this imposes some dangers of not doing string comparisons correctly somewhere, or a typo).

When there is an error (and indicated by the ResponseCode), the value could then hold more specific information (akin to a 404 page in HTTP).

Answer (score 3):

I like the solution you propose.  You may later wish to refactor `ReasonForNoValue` into something more generic, but at least you have the structure to do so if necessary.

Advantages to your approach:

- It's expandable if you ever need to return more data or metadata
- It separates the actual data from the metadata
- There are no `magic numbers`
- It's easy to parse.

Telastyn suggested another good approach - just return a single `TValue` and support a new server call `WhyWasThisNull()`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would most likely use an exception in this case.  Catchy slogans aside, exceptions are the standard way to concisely specify a "success" control flow and an orthogonal "non-success" control flow.  How commonly the non-success path happens has little to do with it, especially when you're adding exception overhead to the much larger database query overhead.

My second choice would be having the calling class implement a result interface, something like this:

```
public class Caller implements ResultHandler {

    public void findValue(Query query) {
        query.execute(this);
    }

    public void valueFound(Value value) {
        System.out.println("Found value " + value);
    }    

    public void valueNotFound(String reason) {
        System.err.println("Value not found: " + reason);
    }
}
```

Like an exception, this solution has the benefit of being unignorable on null values.  This architecture also makes it easy to do other things while you wait for the query to complete.  Also, you should really be putting `valueFound` and `valueNotFound` in their own functions either way.

Your `QueryResult` object is better than returning `null`, but has the drawback of requiring boilerplate code everywhere to check the response code.  If someone later on forgets that boilerplate, or intentionally omits it thinking the value will always be found, there's no telling what state that will put the code into.

In other words, it adds burden on the maintainers.  It may seem blatantly obvious that you need to check the response code now, but it won't be so obvious two years from now.  The more errors are caught by the compiler, the better.

Answer (score 0):

> What other options do I have to communicate the reason?

If your result is a string, you can have the reason be there with some signature that indicates it's a bad result.

If your result is a number, you can have negative (or other bad values) be some error code.

You can have a separate query that users can call (if they so desire) to determine cause of null.

None of these seem clear cut better than your result/error object except perhaps the last depending on your usage.

> What do you think of one event per reason?

I think that events are a largely terrible way to dispatch logic and a fairly rigid/coupled way of signaling a querying error which depends specifically on your data storage/format and would need to change if the query changes to cause different kinds of failure.

Comment: I think that communicating the reason in the string or integer that is returned is the worst possible solution. On the other hand, I don't understand the reasons you bring forward against events. I don't see how the events depend on the "data storage/format" - the reason for a value that couldn't be found is not technical, it is logical, see the example in my comment to the question itself.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - that you have keys at all is an abstraction leakage that you're using a relational database. What happens if you move the translations into a NoSQL style document cache? Different reasons for the thing to not be found. (And yes, the string/int are **horrible** options, but they are options).

Comment: @Telastyn: I strongly disagree that *key* is a leakage of a relational database. In fact, the key has nothing to do with the persistance mechanism. In my specific case, it is the name of the UI control that should be translated. But actually it can be any string, i.e. a GUID. This would work with NoSQL, Cloud, XML... Basically, it is a simple *key -> value* mapping: (translation key, target language) -> text representing *translation key* in *target language*

Comment: In a concurrent system it may not be possible to provide the cause of null later on, because the system state may already have changed.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is do one of this:

**1. Use the QueryResult object but change the name of QueryResult.ReasonForNoValue() to QueryResult.Message()**.

```
public class QueryResult
{
    public TValue Value { get; private set; }
    public TMessage Message { get; private set; }
}
```

**2. Rise KeyUnknowException or NoTranslationException**, although you already said you don't like this solution.

**3. Always return a non-null value**. Only that two special string values exist: "#UKNOWN_KEY" and "#NO_TRANSLATION".

EDIT: (thanx to @DanielHilgarth) You would need to document several things:

1. That a missing value doesn't return `null` but still a `string`.
2. That a missing value is indicated by several magic strings (with the same implications as [magic constants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants)).
3. What each of those magic strings means.

And finally, someone would have to actually read that documentation.
In general, this kind of architecture increases the possibility of bugs.

Comment: Option one is nothing I would ever consider. See the comments on Telastyn's answer as to why.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I read all the comments on Telastyn's answer. Some of them say returning the reason in the return value is "horrible" and the "worst solution", but  explanation of why that is so.

Comment: Because it is an implicit concept. The discoverability of the API is severly hurt. You would need to document several things: (1) That a missing value doesn't return null but still a string. (2) That a missing value is indicated by several magic strings (with the same implications as [magic constants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants)). (3) What each of those magic strings means. And finally, someone would have to actually read that documentation. In general, you increase the possibility of bugs with this kind of architecture.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth You are right. I improved the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use your object and make something like:

```
public class QueryResult
{
    public TValue Value { get; private set; }
    public TQuerySuccess SuccesValue { get; private set; }
}
```

You read the succesvalue to see whether query was sucessful, if it was, value will contain queryresult, if it wasn't value will contain failreason.